# Один проект на гитхабе это 1 репозиторий?

Tags: github

То есть если я делаю компоненты для сайта, то каждый компонент нужно выкладывать в отдельном репозитории- я правильно понимаю?

Comment: компонент !== проект. Компоненты могут быть вообще в одном проекте

Comment: Правил жёстких нет. Туда можно выкладывать всё что угодно в каком угодно виде. Некоторые выкладывают в одном репозитории все учебные задания которые они делали всем скопом за все годы, кто-то все тестовые задания для организаций в одно репе, кто-то ответы на JavaRush, кто-то просто одну страницу с Helloworld, а кто-то готовый модуль для фреймворка например...... что хочется то и делается)))